# RowUpdating event in grid view is not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a grid view and I wanna update data in the row. I have written a C# code and I've noticed that the RowUpdating event is not firing.
I am using Template Field in my grid. The RowCommand event is working properly, however, the RowUpdating event is not firing.
What should I do? I need your help, please.

The event is like the below:

```cs
protected void grdPeople_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strCon);
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            con.Open();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("InsertUpdatePerson", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pr_id", Convert.ToInt32(grdPeople.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()));
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pr_name", (grdPeople.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNameFooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pr_gender", (grdPeople.FooterRow.FindControl("rdoMaleFooter") as RadioButton).Checked);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pr_nationality", (grdPeople.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNationalityFooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pr_idn", (grdPeople.FooterRow.FindControl("txtIDnoFooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pr_passport", (grdPeople.FooterRow.FindControl("txtPassportFooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pr_resident", (grdPeople.FooterRow.FindControl("rdoYesFooter") as RadioButton).Checked);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pr_phone", (grdPeople.FooterRow.FindControl("txtPhoneFooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pr_email", (grdPeople.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEmailFooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ERR_MESSAGE", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ERR_NUMBER", SqlDbType.Int)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        com.ExecuteNonQuery();

        int ErrNo = int.Parse(com.Parameters["@ERR_NUMBER"].Value.ToString());
        if (ErrNo != 0)
        {
            lblSuccess.Text = "Data saved successfully.";
            grdPeople.EditIndex = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.Text = com.Parameters["@ERR_MESSAGE"].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblSuccess.Text = "";
        lblError.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

The below you will find the design of the asp page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="ValidationGridView.Default" EnableEventValidation="false" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <asp:Table runat="server">
                    <asp:TableRow>
                        <asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSearch" />
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSearch" Text="Search" />
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                </asp:Table>
            </div>
            <div>
                <asp:GridView ID="grdPeople" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
                    GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                    OnRowCommand="grdPeople_RowCommand"
                    OnRowEditing="grdPeople_RowEditing"
                    OnRowCancelingEdit="grdPeople_RowCancelingEdit"
                    OnRowUpdating="grdPeople_RowUpdating"
                    ShowFooter="true" DataKeyNames="pr_id">

                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />

                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pr_name") %>' ID="lblName" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" Text='<%# Bind("pr_name") %>' runat="server" />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtName" ErrorMessage="Name is required." ForeColor="Red" Text="*" ValidationGroup="Fields" />
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNameFooter" />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNameFooter" ErrorMessage="Name is required." ForeColor="Red" Text="*" ValidationGroup="FieldsFooter" />
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("pr_gender") %>' runat="server" ID="lblGender" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoMale" Text ="Male" Checked='<%# Bind("pr_gender_value") %>' GroupName="Gender" runat="server" />
                                <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoFemale" Text="Female" runat="server" GroupName="Gender" />
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoMaleFooter" Text="Male" checked="true" runat="server" GroupName="Gender" />
                                <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoFemaleFooter" Text="Female" runat="server" GroupName="Gender" />
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nationality">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("pr_nationality") %>' runat="server" ID="lblNationality" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNationality" Text='<%# Bind("pr_nationality") %>' runat="server" />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" ControlToValidate="txtNationality" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Nationality is required." ForeColor="Red" Text="*" ValidationGroup="Fields" />
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNationalityFooter" runat="server" />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNationalityFooter" ErrorMessage="Nationality is required." ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="FieldsFooter" Text="*" />
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID Number">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("pr_idn") %>' runat="server" ID="lblIDNo" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtIDNo" Text='<%# Bind("pr_idn") %>' runat="server" />
                                <asp:CustomValidator ID="cstIDNo" runat="server" Text="*" ControlToValidate="txtIDNo" ForeColor="Red" ValidateEmptyText="True" ValidationGroup="Fields" />
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtIDnoFooter" runat="server" />
                                <asp:CustomValidator ID="cstIDNoFooter" runat="server" Text="*" ControlToValidate="txtIDnoFooter" ForeColor="Red" ValidateEmptyText="True" ValidationGroup="FieldsFooter" />
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Passport">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("pr_passport") %>' runat="server" ID="lblPassport" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassport" Text='<%# Bind("pr_passport") %>' runat="server" />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPassport" ErrorMessage="Passport is required." ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="Fields" Text="*" />
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassportFooter" runat="server" />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPassportFooter" ErrorMessage="Passport is required." ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="FieldsFooter" Text="*" />
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Resident">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("pr_resident") %>' runat="server" ID="lblResident" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoYes" Text="Yes" Checked='<%# Bind("pr_resident_value") %>' GroupName="Resident" runat="server" />
                                <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoNo" Text="No" runat="server" GroupName="Resident" />
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoYesFooter" Text="Yes" Checked="true" GroupName="Resident" runat="server" />
                                <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoNoFooter" Text="No" runat="server" GroupName="Resident" />
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Phone">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("pr_phone") %>' runat="server" ID="lblPhone" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" Text='<%# Bind("pr_phone") %>' runat="server" />
                                <asp:CustomValidator ID="cstPhone" runat="server" Text="*" ControlToValidate="txtPhone" ForeColor="Red" ValidateEmptyText="True" ValidationGroup="Fields" />
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhoneFooter" runat="server" />
                                <asp:CustomValidator ID="cstPhoneFooter" runat="server" Text="*" ControlToValidate="txtPhoneFooter" ForeColor="Red" ValidateEmptyText="True" ValidationGroup="FieldsFooter" />
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("pr_email") %>' runat="server" ID="lblEmail" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" Text='<%# Bind("pr_email") %>' runat="server" />
                                <asp:CustomValidator ID="cstEmail" runat="server" Text="*" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ForeColor="Red" ValidateEmptyText="True" ValidationGroup="Fields" />
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailFooter" runat="server" />
                                <asp:CustomValidator ID="cstEmailFooter" runat="server" Text="*" ControlToValidate="txtEmailFooter" ForeColor="Red" ValidateEmptyText="True" ValidationGroup="FieldsFooter" />
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="~/icons/edit.png" CommandName="Edit" ToolTip="Edit" Width="20px" Height="20px" />
                                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="~/icons/delete.png" CommandName="Delete" ToolTip="Delete" Width="20px" Height="20px" />
                                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="~/icons/email.png" CommandName="Mail" ToolTip="Mail" Width="20px" Height="20px" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="~/icons/save.png" CommandName="Save" ToolTip="Save" Width="20px" Height="20px" ValidationGroup="Fields"/>
                                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="~/icons/cancel.png" CommandName="Cancel" ToolTip="Cancel" Width="20px" Height="20px" />
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnInsert" ImageUrl="~/icons/add.png" ValidationGroup="FieldsFooter" CommandName="Insert" ToolTip="Insert" Width="20px" Height="20px" />
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <br />
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSuccess" ForeColor="Green" />
                <br />
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblError" ForeColor="Red" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnImportExl" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/icons/excel.png" Width="40px" Height="40px" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="Fields" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I added the grid design above to show you how I designed it and how I set its properties.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `GridView`'s `EditItemTemplate`, you miss out a button with `CommandName="Update"` which this button will trigger the `grdPeople_RowUpdating` event.

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="~/icons/save.png" CommandName="Save" ToolTip="Save" Width="20px" Height="20px" ValidationGroup="Fields"/>
    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="~/icons/cancel.png" CommandName="Cancel" ToolTip="Cancel" Width="20px" Height="20px" />
</EditItemTemplate>
```

---

### SOLUTION

Change the Save button `CommandName`'s value from `CommandName="Save"` to `CommandName="Update"`.

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="~/icons/save.png" CommandName="Update" ToolTip="Save" Width="20px" Height="20px" ValidationGroup="Fields"/>
    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="~/icons/cancel.png" CommandName="Cancel" ToolTip="Cancel" Width="20px" Height="20px" />
</EditItemTemplate>
```

---

### REFERENCE

[Edit and Update Record in GridView in ASP.Net](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/edit-and-update-record-in-gridview-in-Asp-Net/)